# JQuery snake game score board disappearing after game over

Tags: html, jquery

I've developed a snake game in jQuery and HTML. I'm displaying score on top of the gameboard. It's all going well but when the game is over and need to restart it again, the score is disappearing and it's not being displayed again. When I reload the page, It's showing again.

Since I can't post this question with less text, I'm typing all this random passage. Sorry for this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var score;
   init();
});
var score=0;
var move;
function init() {
    board.initBoard();
    createSnake();
    food.createFood();
}

function play() {

    $('.newGame').hide();
    $('.playgame').hide();
    moveSnake();
    getSnakeDir();
}

function gameover() {
 console.log(score);
    clearTimeout(move);
    $('.newGame').show();
}

function playGame() {
score=0;
    
    $('#gameboard').empty();
    $('.newGame').hide();
    init();
    play();
}

var board = {
    DIM: 20,
    initBoard: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
            var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');
            
            for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
                var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
                $(row).append(col);
            }
            $("#gameboard").append(row);
        }
    }
}

var snake = {
    position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
    direction: 'r',
    speed: 200,
};

function createSnake() {
    $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
    $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
    snake.position = ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'];
}

function getSnakeDir() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        if (event.which == 38) {
            snake.direction = 'u';
        } else if (event.which == 39) {
            snake.direction = 'r';
        } else if (event.which == 40) {
            snake.direction = 'd';
        } else if (event.which == 37) {
            snake.direction = 'l';
        }
    });
}

function moveSnake() {
    var tail = snake.position.pop();
    $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');

    var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
    var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
    var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
        x = x + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
        y = y + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
        x = x - 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
        y = y - 1;
    }
    
    var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
    snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

    $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

    //when snake eats food
    if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
        console.log('true');
        score= score+10;
        $('#scoreb').html("Score :" +score);
        $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
        snake.position.push(tail);
        food.createFood();
    }

    //game over
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
        gameover();
        $('#scoreb').show();
        return;
    
    }

    //if snake touch itself
    if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
        gameover();
        return;
    }
    
    move=setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
}

var food = {
    coords: "",

    createFood: function() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
        $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
        food.coords = fruitCoords;
    },
}

function hitItself(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<style>
.buttonnewgame {
     position: relative;
}

.newGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
     font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
       
}
.instructions
{
margin-left: 5px;
float: left;
position : relative;
color: #c603fc;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.gameContainer{
    width:100%;
}
#scoreb
{
z-index: 999;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#gameboard {
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:3px;
}

.playgame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
       
}

/* styling the board */
div[class^='row'] {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

div[class*='col']{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

/*display the snake*/
.snake {

    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
}

.food {
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td><div class="game">
    <div class="buttonnewgame">
       <center><input type="button" name="New game" value="Game over! New game" class="newGame" style="display:none;" onclick="playGame()" />
        <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button></center> 
        <div class="gameContainer">
      
            <div id="gameboard">
          <div id="scoreb"> Score : </div>               
               <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </div></div></td>
        <td width="150">
    <div class="instructions" >
      OBJECT: Get as many pieces of "food" as possible using your arrow keys.  Each time you do this, you will grow.   You want to try to get as big as possible without crashing into a wall or back onto yourself.  Good Luck!!
      </div></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You empty all tag inside `#gameboard` but you need to empty all except `scoreb`.
So instead of `$('#gameboard').empty();` use `$('#gameboard').find('*').not('#scoreb').remove();`

And note that you must reset the value of `score` by:  `$('#scoreb').text("Score :0")`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var score;
   init();
});
var score=0;
var move;
function init() {
    board.initBoard();
    createSnake();
    food.createFood();
}

function play() {

    $('.newGame').hide();
    $('.playgame').hide();
    moveSnake();
    getSnakeDir();
}

function gameover() {
 console.log(score);
    clearTimeout(move);
    $('.newGame').show();
}

function playGame() {
score=0;
    
    //$('#gameboard').empty();
    $('#gameboard').find('*').not('#scoreb').remove();
    $('#scoreb').text("Score :0")
    $('.newGame').hide();
    init();
    play();
}

var board = {
    DIM: 20,
    initBoard: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
            var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');
            
            for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
                var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
                $(row).append(col);
            }
            $("#gameboard").append(row);
        }
    }
}

var snake = {
    position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
    direction: 'r',
    speed: 200,
};

function createSnake() {
    $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
    $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
    snake.position = ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'];
}

function getSnakeDir() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        if (event.which == 38) {
            snake.direction = 'u';
        } else if (event.which == 39) {
            snake.direction = 'r';
        } else if (event.which == 40) {
            snake.direction = 'd';
        } else if (event.which == 37) {
            snake.direction = 'l';
        }
    });
}

function moveSnake() {
    var tail = snake.position.pop();
    $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');

    var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
    var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
    var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
        x = x + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
        y = y + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
        x = x - 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
        y = y - 1;
    }
    
    var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
    snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

    $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

    //when snake eats food
    if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
        console.log('true');
        score= score+10;
        $('#scoreb').html("Score :" +score);
        $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
        snake.position.push(tail);
        food.createFood();
    }

    //game over
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
        gameover();
        $('#scoreb').show();
        return;
    
    }

    //if snake touch itself
    if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
        gameover();
        return;
    }
    
    move=setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
}

var food = {
    coords: "",

    createFood: function() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
        $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
        food.coords = fruitCoords;
    },
}

function hitItself(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<style>
.buttonnewgame {
     position: relative;
}

.newGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
     font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
       
}
.instructions
{
margin-left: 5px;
float: left;
position : relative;
color: #c603fc;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.gameContainer{
    width:100%;
}
#scoreb
{
z-index: 999;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#gameboard {
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:3px;
}

.playgame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
       
}

/* styling the board */
div[class^='row'] {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

div[class*='col']{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

/*display the snake*/
.snake {

    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
}

.food {
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td><div class="game">
    <div class="buttonnewgame">
       <center><input type="button" name="New game" value="Game over! New game" class="newGame" style="display:none;" onclick="playGame()" />
        <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button></center> 
        <div class="gameContainer">
      
            <div id="gameboard">
          <div id="scoreb"> Score : </div>               
               <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </div></div></td>
        <td width="150">
    <div class="instructions" >
      OBJECT: Get as many pieces of "food" as possible using your arrow keys.  Each time you do this, you will grow.   You want to try to get as big as possible without crashing into a wall or back onto yourself.  Good Luck!!
      </div></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: @ Don't forgot you need to rest the value of `score` after new game by this line of code: `$('#scoreb').text("Score :0")`

Comment: When the game is over and restarted, there's one tail left behind at the starting point and the remaining snake is moving ahead. Could u please help with a fix for that. image : ibb.co/nnP6HDR

Comment: In `createSnake` method remove `$('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');` code

Answer (score 1):

Your scoreboard is in the `#gameboard`. When the line `$('#gameboard').empty();` is executed, the scoreboard is removed.

Move the line `<div id="scoreb"> Score : </div>` to out of `#gameboard`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var score;
  init();
});
var score = 0;
var move;

function init() {
  board.initBoard();
  createSnake();
  food.createFood();
}

function play() {

  $('.newGame').hide();
  $('.playgame').hide();
  moveSnake();
  getSnakeDir();
}

function gameover() {
  console.log(score);
  clearTimeout(move);
  $('.newGame').show();
}

function playGame() {
  score = 0;

  $('#gameboard').empty();
  $('.newGame').hide();
  init();
  play();
}

var board = {
  DIM: 20,
  initBoard: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
      var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');

      for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
        var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
        $(row).append(col);
      }
      $("#gameboard").append(row);
    }
  }
}

var snake = {
  position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
  direction: 'r',
  speed: 200,
};

function createSnake() {
  $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
  $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
  snake.position = ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'];
}

function getSnakeDir() {
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which == 38) {
      snake.direction = 'u';
    } else if (event.which == 39) {
      snake.direction = 'r';
    } else if (event.which == 40) {
      snake.direction = 'd';
    } else if (event.which == 37) {
      snake.direction = 'l';
    }
  });
}

function moveSnake() {
  var tail = snake.position.pop();
  $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');

  var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
  var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
  var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

  if (snake.direction == 'r') {
    x = x + 1;
  } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
    y = y + 1;
  } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
    x = x - 1;
  } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
    y = y - 1;
  }

  var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
  snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

  $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

  //when snake eats food
  if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
    console.log('true');
    score = score + 10;
    $('#scoreb').html("Score :" + score);
    $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
    snake.position.push(tail);
    food.createFood();
  }

  //game over
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
    gameover();
    $('#scoreb').show();
    return;

  }

  //if snake touch itself
  if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
    gameover();
    return;
  }

  move = setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
}

var food = {
  coords: "",

  createFood: function() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM - 1)) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM - 1)) + 1;
    var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
    $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
    food.coords = fruitCoords;
  },
}

function hitItself(array) {
  var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var value = array[i];
    if (value in valuesSoFar) {
      return true;
    }
    valuesSoFar[value] = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.buttonnewgame {
  position: relative;
}

.newGame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font: normal;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #FF69B4;
}

.instructions {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: #c603fc;
  font: normal;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gameContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

#scoreb {
  z-index: 999;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#gameboard {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
}

.playgame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  font: normal;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #FF69B4;
}


/* styling the board */

div[class^='row'] {
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

div[class*='col'] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}


/*display the snake*/

.snake {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 99;
}

.food {
  background: red;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="game">
        <div class="buttonnewgame">
          <center><input type="button" name="New game" value="Game over! New game" class="newGame" style="display:none;" onclick="playGame()" />
            <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button></center>
          <div class="gameContainer">

            <div id="scoreb"> Score : </div>
            <div id="gameboard">
              <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <div class="instructions">
        OBJECT: Get as many pieces of "food" as possible using your arrow keys. Each time you do this, you will grow. You want to try to get as big as possible without crashing into a wall or back onto yourself. Good Luck!!
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When the game is over and restarted, there's one tail left behind at the starting point and the remaining snake is moving ahead. Could u please help with a fix for that. image : ibb.co/nnP6HDR